# Matching colors for video

Tags: premiere, colorspace

It appears that loading a graphics asset into Premiere’s [new (2017.1)](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2306606) layered drawing tools does not do any kind of profile matching.  Furthermore, the play preview image looks different on my (color calibrated) monitor than it does on a real television.

Generally, the encoded video played on the TV looks more washed out, showing more shadow detail.  Specifically in this case, the [desired green](https://identityguide.unt.edu/create-our-look/color) is significantly lighter and perhaps is more yellowish but that could just be the impression due to the brightness difference.

How do I convert a specified color into the RGB codes to use in Premiere’s titling tools?  I’m guessing at this point that I want to know the colors in the [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) color space, and that “hex color is #00853E” is sRGB.

Comment: Do the layered drawing tools have a color picker? Perhaps you could just pick the color directly from something else that uses it?

Comment: I did in fact use the color picker on the UNT logo in the playback window.  But if it didn’t color-manage the importing of the logo file in the first place, that doesn’t help.

Comment: The difference between the play preview image on your monitor vs. the TV is likely due to a data/video level mismatch somewhere.  How are you getting the video onto the TV?  Onto the monitor?

Comment: @JasonConrad the HT-PC uses an HDMI connector to a Denon receiver which takes the sound and passes along the picture to the TV, by another HDMI.

Comment: So through that signal path, I imagine you've rendered the video out to a file and are playing it through a software application?  You mentioned a color calibrated monitor.  I assume that's a separate signal path.  Does the play preview run through a hardware video interface such as a BlackMagic mini monitor or AJA box?  I'm guessing that your problems stem from mismatched data/video levels between these two signal paths.  This tutorial will help diagnose your issue.  Free trial available. https://mixinglight.com/color-tutorial/calman-part-10-using-calibration-test-patterns-in-your-nle/

Comment: @JasonConrad my editing PC running Premeire plays the preview in a window on the attached monitor via DisplayPort.  The display is calibrated in Windows using Spyder 3.

Comment: What sort of monitor will the audience for this video watch it on? There's no point getting too concerned with precise colour if everyone who sees the video is going to be seeing it on different randomly un-calibrated monitors in wildly varying viewing environments. Just do the best you can; fretting about colour profiles is for print designers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that BT.709 is a larger standard that includes the sRGB color space as part of what it means.  The Wikipedia article says “based on”, but looking carefully at the chart of numbers, they are identical.  So there is no need to *convert* from one to the other.

Of the various mixing recipes given (which do not agree with each other), the hex code is said to be for HTML/CSS, so that one I can assume is for the sRGB color space.

I used that value in Premiere in the new Graphics drawing tools, and it looks like the right kind of green.

The green background in the white-on-green EPS file they provide for the logo is not the right green when simply imported into Premiere, as I noted.  So I loaded it into Illustrator, turned off the background, and saved as the white logo *only*.  This I imported into Premiere which I layered over the background color, drawn using Premiere’s shape tool.